# Compose: How to have ime padding and Scaffold padding with edge-to-edge and windowSoftInputMode is adjustResize

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, edge-to-edge

The `androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold` padding wrongly adds the Navigation Bar padding even when soft keyboard is open the IME padding is added, resulting in a double amount of Navigation Bar padding (see screenshot below, the divider should be touching the top of the soft keyboard).

I'm trying to have the following thing to work together:

1. App is [edge-to-edge](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge)
2. `windowSoftInputMode` is `adjustResize`
3. having my content inside a `androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold`

This is the code of the `MainActivity`:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        setContent {
            MyComposeApplicationTheme {
                Scaffold(
                    topBar = {
                        TopAppBar(
                            title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)) }
                        )
                    },
                ) { scaffoldPadding ->
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(scaffoldPadding),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
                    ) {
                        OutlinedTextField(
                            value = "",
                            onValueChange = {},
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                        )
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how it looks:
[image]

But, if I open the keyboard, the screen does not resizes correctly, despite having the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` attribute inside the `AndroidManifest` set for the Activity:
[image]

If I use the `Modifier.imePadding()`, the situation is improving but now I have, beside the padding for the IME, also the inner padding of the Scaffold that is taking into account the padding for the Navigation Bar even when the keyboard is open:
[image]

What is the right way to keep the Scaffold bottom padding without it adding the Navigation Bar padding when the IME padding is added?

EDIT
I suspect this is a bug of the `Scaffold` so I've created an issue on the tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249727298

Comment: Maybe you can add a copy of the answer you found in the issuetracker - I am sure others will have the same issue and end up here :)

Comment: @mama hey sure, I'll do it immediately.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently there is no clean solution but the following workaround seems to work fine: passing `WindowInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)` to `Scaffold` and then applying `.padding(scaffoldPadding).consumedWindowInsets(scaffoldPadding).systemBarsPadding()` internally, or applying `imePadding()` internally as well.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        setContent {
            MyComposeApplicationTheme {
                Scaffold(
                    modifier = Modifier.imePadding(),
                    topBar = {
                        TopAppBar(
                            title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)) }
                        )
                    },
                    bottomBar = {
                        BottomAppBar() {
                            IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                                Icon(Icons.Default.Build, null)
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)
                ) { scaffoldPadding ->
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(scaffoldPadding)
                            .consumedWindowInsets(scaffoldPadding)
                            .systemBarsPadding(),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
                    ) {
                        OutlinedTextField(
                            value = "",
                            onValueChange = {},
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)

                        )
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what of a case where i don't have a bottomBar and i don't need the unnecessary padding at the bottom...?

Comment: What I'm doing is to have multiple Scaffolds, once per NavGraph destination. This way each screen can have its own padding/fab.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the keyboard opens up, for some reasons the values in scaffoldPadding are erroneous.

I have a TopBar but not a BottomBar. ScaffoldPadding value should be :

- Top:64
- Bottom:0
- Start:0
- End:0

But are (only after the keyboard was opened) :

- Top:64
- Bottom:48 (the bug ?)
- Start:0
- End:0

Personally to fix my issue of having en extra bottom padding in the Scaffold is not to apply the given scaffoldPadding.

```
        Scaffold(
        snackbarHost = { ...},
        topBar = { ...},
        content = { scaffoldPadding ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = scaffoldPadding.calculateTopPadding())
            ) {
               ...
            }
        }
    )
```